# Confused with school assignment

Tags: java

Instructions: Write a program that uses the Monte Carlo sampling method to estimate
the average number of bottles of e-Boost someone would have to drink to
win a prize. There is a 1 in 5 chance that a bottle cap will have a prize.

1. Create a new project called Monte Carlo Method in the
   Unit05 Assessments folder.
2. Create a class called BottleCapPrize in the newly created
   project folder.
3. Determine how many bottle caps each person has to open in
   order to find a winning cap. (This represents one trial.)
   Print this value to a text file. Review Dr. Lin’s suggestion
   about performing this simulation with dice.
4. Prompt the user for the number of trials. Conduct at least 1000 trials.
5. Read back the data for all of the trials from the output file.
6. Calculate the average number of caps opened in order to win a prize.
7. Print the result to the screen.

edit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class BottleCapPrize
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("bottleCap.txt"));
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int counter = 0;
        int winCounter = 0;       

        Random randNum = new Random();
        int randNumber = randNum.nextInt(5) + 1;

        System.out.print("How many trails would you like to do?");
        int trials = input.nextInt();

        while(trials != 1)
        {             
            //Random randNum = new Random();
            randNumber = randNum.nextInt(5) + 1;

            while(randNumber != 1)
            {                    
                if(randNumber != 1)
                {               
                    //System.out.println("You don't win");
                }
                else if(randNumber == 1)
                {
                    winCounter++;
                    outFile.println(counter);
                    System.out.println("You win in " + counter + "                bottles");
                    winCounter++;
                    //System.out.println("counter: " + counter + "\tWin counter: " + winCounter);
                } 
                counter++;
            }
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great. So what is the confusion about this ?

Comment: And what have you tried so far (other than asking us to write the entirety of your assignment for you)? - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Jabir I edited my original post and added the code I've already written.

Comment: @Jonnus I edited my original post and added the code I've already written.

Comment: What is the issue with above code ?

Comment: @Jabir whenever I enter the number of trials I want to be done, there is a unending loop that doesn't seem to accept my input. So for example if I enter in 10 trials and then press enter, the cursor just moves down a line and prompts me to enter another input

Comment: That's because your loop is while trials != 1, but you never set trials to be 1. A for loop using your counter less than 10 would be a better conduct to use here

Comment: @Jonnus I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: Google of "Java for loop" = http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_for_loops.html

Comment: Ohhh I see, I misread your comment. Thank you, I think that solves my issue!

Answer (score 0):

*(This answer is converting [the comments under the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114895/confused-with-school-assignment#comment55979830_34114895) into a formal answer)*

You are experiencing an unending (infinite) loop, as you are using the construct

```
while(trials != 1)
```

Yet never setting `trials` to `1`.

If you want the loop to execute 10 times only you should use a for loop and a counter (I note that you already have a counter you are incrementing every iteration, but is itself not referenced).

Using a for loop of the following structure should help when replacing the line `while(trials != 1)` referenced above

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
```